# Stop auto triggering a click after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that fill in an **input field** and then triggers a click on a **submit button** within a form if a certain text exists in a specific div, so that makes a pages refresh on submit.

I also have a **link** inside the same form that if clicked it removes the **input value** that was filled before and also submit the form. Since it submit the form, it triggers a page refresh which leads to executing the first event that fill in the **input field** and trigger a click on the **submit button** again.

I want to stop auto triggering that click if the **link** was clicked by the user.

Perhaps the code explain better...

---

#### JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#link").click(function () {
        sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = true;
        window.location.reload();
    });

    $(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad) {
            //Some code that I don't know to prevent executing the below code after page refresh if #link was clicked by user.
            alert("Link Clicked");
            sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = false;
        }
    });

    if (document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML.indexOf("Sampletext") != -1) {
        document.getElementById('inputid').value = 'example';
        $("#button").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

#### HTML :

```
<div id="divid">Sampletext</div>
<input type="text" id="inputid" /> 
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Enter" />
<a href="?p=dothis" id="link">Do This</a>
```

Answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting the reloadAfterPageLoad flag, but then you aren't doing anything *meaningful* with it.

Try replacing the bottom part of your code with something like this;

```
if (document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML.indexOf("Sampletext") != -1 && sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageReload == true) {
     document.getElementById('inputid').value = 'example';
     $("#button").trigger('click');
   }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it disabled the whole event without clicking on the `#link`, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an item in local storage that you use to determine if the click has been triggered, you could use that to determine if it should trigger after reload.  local storage persist between page request.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var triggered = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('triggered'));

    $("#link").click(function () {
        sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = true;
        window.location.reload();
    });

    $(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad) {
            //Some code that I don't know to prevent executing the below code after page refresh if #link was clicked by user.
            alert("Link Clicked");
            sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = false;
        }
    });

    if (document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML.indexOf("Sampletext") != -1) {
        document.getElementById('inputid').value = 'example';
        if (!triggered) {
            localStorage.setItem('triggered', 1);
            $("#button").trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```